# How to make uchiwa dashboard url be able to adjust threshold?

Tags: plugins, dashboard, sensu

me again..

I had done all the sensu-uchiwa-graphite set up. And i get a new request,:(. Rather than go to change the threshold in check.json file on sensu server..any plugin at the UCHIWA that this adjustment will be shown in Uchiwa dashboard? I asked because in case that my application teams wanna change it by themselves without accessing to server.

I think sensu-admin in enterprise is available but we need to pay big money per year ;(...

Thanks in advance to help.

Sumana W.

Comment: No, you can't. Uchiwa can't even show check definitions. There are no plugins to uchiwa either.

Comment: @Kobbe .. thanks for this information :).. i will hang on with only silence and   unsilence modes.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly doable if you use a configuration management system like Chef/Ansible/Puppet - especially if you run standalone checks on the sensu-client.

This allows the clients to define their own thresholds, rather than changing the sensu servers themselves.

See https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/checks.html#standalone-checks

In this case, the definitions for the checks are sitting on the client servers and they have the choice of their thresholds or configurations. The client itself manages how often to run the check and sends the output back to the server, rather than the server requesting the checks. This helps quite a bit as far as scaling or multitenancy.

The other way to accomplish this, if you are tied to serverside checks, would be to use client attributes (https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.25/reference/checks.html#check-token-substitution)

For example, you can have a cpu check that says something like `check-cpu.sh -w :::cpu_warn::: -c :::cpu_critical:::` and these come from a `cpu_warn` and `cpu_critical` value from the client.json on the client server.

Source: We use sensu extensively in an enterprise environment across thousands of hosts and have been working through these same issues.

Comment: Thanks very much.. i will try this too. :)